# How can I line up the grid in groups of four in qml, by using the gridview?

Tags: qt, gridview, qml

cccc  cccc  cccc  cccc

In this case, the "c" is the a grid of the gridview.

I want to line up the grids in this way.

How can I solve it?

I am using the qml.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this by adding empty items at every 5th position:

```
GridView {
    model: 20
    anchors.fill: parent
    cellWidth: 20

    delegate: Rectangle {
        Label {
            // add text or a space for each 5th element
            text: ((index) % 5 === 0) ? " " : (index - Math.ceil(index / 5))
        }

    }
}
```

[image]

Still I think, GridView is not the perfect match for your task.